# Returning checked checkboxes based on pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

This question is regarding Laravel and PHP.

I am building a form that allows users (players) to be assigned to / de-assigned from a team using checkboxes.

Many users can belong to many teams. I have a pivot table team_user to manage the many-to-many relationship.

I am having trouble populating the checkboxes based on whether the association exists in the pivot table.

So far I have them in two separate 'bits', which you can see below:

My Controller:

```
$users_checked = $team->users()->get();
$users = User::all();
return View::make('team/addplayers', compact('users', 'team', 'users_checked'));
```

My View:

```
@foreach ($users_checked as $user_checked)
    <p>
    {{ Form::checkbox('player[]', $user_checked->id, true) }}
    {{ Form::label('email', $user_checked->email) }}
    </p>
@endforeach

@foreach($users as $user)
    <p>
    {{ Form::checkbox('player[]', $user->id ) }}
    {{ Form::label('email', $user->email) }}
    </p>
@endforeach
```

What is the most sensible way to 'combine' these into one list, where the checkbox is ticked if the association exists in the pivot, or not ticked if it doesn't?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may try something like this:

```
$teams = Team::with('users')->get();
return View::make('team/addplayers', compact('teams'));
```

In your view:

```
@foreach ($teams as $team)
    @foreach ($team->users as $user)
        <p>
            {{ Form::checkbox(
                   'player[]',
                   $user->id,
                   (in_array($user->id, $team->users->fetch('id')) ? 1 : 0)
               )
            }}
            {{ Form::label('email', $user->email) }}
        </p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel this is close, but I'm getting "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array", maybe something to do with it being an object rather than an array (not sure)

Answer (score 6):

The answers put me on the right track, thank you. My actual solution is below:

In my controller:

```
public function showAddPlayer(Team $team)
{
    $users = User::all();
    return View::make('team/addplayers', compact('users', 'team'));
}
```

In my view:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>
        {{ Form::checkbox('player[]', $user->id, $team->users->contains($user->id)) }}
        {{ Form::label('email', $user->email) }}
    </p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: More information about contains() in Laravel Collections: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-contains

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ Form::checkbox('player[]', $user->id,in_array($user->id, $users_checked->lists('id')) ? 1 : 0 ) }}
```